# Moodle lost themes & features

Tags: linux, themes, moodle

I install Moodle on Centos7 with LEMP.
Right after I finished the installation process, I started to creat user.
However, the page is plain text, I mean it's like cannot load any css js file(sry, i dont have enough reputation to post a image) even though this is the 1st setup. it should come up with a default skin. 
Can you guys please help me fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it fixed once you have created the user and logged in?

Have you tried using your browser developer tools to identify which file paths are failing to load?

Are you able to get as far as to be able to change the theme on your site to see if that helps? (Site admin > Appearance > Theme selector)

Can you try purging the caches (Site admin > Developer > Purge all caches), to see if that helps?